ABP Framework separate Auth server and admin ASP.NET MVC login configuration not working
I am using the ABP Framework EventHub sample project as an inspiration for my next app. I have taken this concept of having a separate auth server using ABPs identity packages. This works fine and I am able to login as a user and see the account page.
The auth server is located at this address:  https://localhost:44382
The issue that I am facing is trying to hook this up to the ASP.NET MVC admin panel which is located at this address: https://localhost:44397/Account/Login.
I get to the Login page, I enter my credentials but I'm redirected back to the homepage but the system failed to log me in.
This is what I have in my admin ASP.NET MVC WebModule.cs file:
private void ConfigureAuthentication(ServiceConfigurationContext context, IConfiguration configuration)
{
    context.Services.AddAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultScheme = "Cookies";
            options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "oidc";
        })
        .AddCookie("Cookies", options =>
            {
                options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(365);
            })
        .AddAbpOpenIdConnect("oidc", options =>
            {
                options.Authority = configuration["AuthServer:Authority"];
                options.RequireHttpsMetadata = Convert.ToBoolean(configuration["AuthServer:RequireHttpsMetadata"]);
                options.ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.CodeIdToken;

                options.ClientId = configuration["AuthServer:ClientId"];
                options.ClientSecret = configuration["AuthServer:ClientSecret"];

                options.SaveTokens = true;
                options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;

                // options.Scope.Add("role");
                // options.Scope.Add("email");
                // options.Scope.Add("phone");
                options.Scope.Add("BasicTheme");
            });
}

Now I know this is not going to work since the admin ASP.NET MVC project does not know anything about my auth server and this is the part that I am struggling with in how to setup the communication.
I have looked at all the examples the ABP provides but none of them have any examples showing how to hook an admin ASP.NET MVC based project to a separate auth server.
The expected outcome is for an admin user to login, hits my separate auth server and then redirects to the admin dashboard.
